# Перебрать 4-битное число. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, перебор

Допустим, есть переменная bits с числом и answer.

```
bits = 4
answer = 1111
```

Нужно перебрать значения `(0000, 0001...1111)` а потом сравнивать с `answer`, а если переменная равна `answer`, вывести ее на экран. Еще одна задача - чтобы если переменная `bits` менялась (допустим она становилось цифрой 8), перебираемые значения тоже должны изменяться `(00000000, 00000001...11111111)`

Я пытался это сделать так:

```
bits = 4
answer = "1111"

x = bits*bits
y = []
for n in range(len(answer)):
    y.insert(n, 0)
for i in range(x):
    ans = ""
    for j in range(len(answer)):
        if y[j] == 0:
            ans += "0"
            y[j] = n
        else:
            ans += "1"
    print(ans)
```

Но при этом, выдавало `0000`, а на следующий раз `1111`

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @strawdog это не учебная задача, но конечно же я приведу код, в котором у меня (конечно же) ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно использовать модуль `itertools`

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product("01", repeat = 4):
    print("".join(i))
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = '1111'

for i in range(0b1111 + 1): 
    if f'{i:04b}' == answer:
        print(answer)
```

> Еще одна задача - чтобы если переменная bits менялась (допустим она становилось цифрой 8),  перебираемые значения тоже должны изменяться (00000000, 00000001...11111111)

```
bits = 8

for i in range(2**bits):
    print(f'{i:0{bits}b}')
```

В строке форматирования `f'{i:04b}'`:

- `b` - переводить в двоичный (binary) вид
- `04` - дополнять до 4 символов нулями слева (если оставить просто 4 без нуля, то будет дополняться пробелами)

В варианте с задаваемым переменной количеством бит вместо 4 из первого примера просто подставляется количество символов.

---

Вообще, лучше обойтись без строкового представления, перебирать и сравнивать целые числа, а в виде набора бит выводить только результат:

```
answer = 0b1111

for i in range(0b1111 + 1): 
    if i == answer:
        print(f'{i:04b}')
```

Answer (score 1):

если не использовать строки (с ними все быстрее) и библиотеки, то:

```
value = 0

while value != 11111111111111:

    tmp = value + 1
    value = 0
    overflow = 0

    index = 0
    finish = False

    while finish is False:

        if tmp == 0:
            finish = True

        digit = tmp % 10 + overflow
        tmp //= 10

        overflow = digit > 1
        digit %= 2

        value += digit * 10**index
        index += 1

    print(value)
```

Comment: можно просто получить с помощью `range` все значения от `0` до `2 ** 4` и вывести его в двоичном виде

Comment: @Danis, да, думал об этом, но решил в лоб сделать чтобы не возиться с переводом, поскольку думал, что автору 111 именно в десятичном виде нужно